# Trying to calculate large numbers in Python with gmpy. Python keeps crashing?

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, gmp

I was recommended to use gmpy to assist with calculating large numbers efficiently. Before I was just using python and my script ran for a day or two and then ran out of memory (not sure how that happened because my program's memory usage should basically be constant throughout.. maybe a memory leak?)

Anyways, I keep getting this weird error after running my program for a couple seconds:

```
mp_allocate< 545275904->545275904 >
Fatal Python error: mp_allocate failure

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. 
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Also, python crashes and Windows 7 gives me the generic `python.exe has stopped working` dialog.

This wasn't happening with using standard python integers. Now that I switch to gmpy I am getting this error just seconds in to running my script. I thought gmpy was specialized in dealing with large number arithmetic?

For reference, here is a sample program that produces the error:

```
import gmpy2

p = gmpy2.xmpz(3000000000)
s = gmpy2.xmpz(2)
M = s**p

for x in range(p):
    s = (s * s) % M
```

I have 10 gigs of RAM and without gmpy this script ran for days without running out of memory (still not sure how that happened considering `s` never really gets larger..

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention I am using Python 3.2

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's `**`, not `*`. Overlooked that. Good one.

Comment: @RichieHindle is right; also, if you're using Python 2, use `xrange` instead of `range`. In Python 2, `range` returns a list, which in this case would contain 3,000,000,000 elements, a bit much even for 10 GB of RAM.

Comment: @TomZych: I'm using Python 3 and apparently xrange does not exist?

Comment: Then it's the answer in @RichieHindle's comment, which has unaccountably disappeared. He pointed out that `2**3000000000` is probably too big to fit in your machine's address space. Try it with one billion instead and see if that works.

Comment: @Tom Zych: I removed the comment because it was technically wrong (something like "2^3G won't fit in a 32-bit address space", which is actually not true - I was muddling bits and bytes).  But it seems the problem *is* due to the "small" address space of 32-bit Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of gmpy and gmpy2.**

I won't be able to test this until tonight. But a couple of comments and questions.

Instead of using (s * s) % M, use pow(s, 2, M). It should be faster.

What happens if you use gmpy2.mpz() instead of gmpy2.xmpz() ?

Are you running a 64-bit version of Python and gmpy2? (I assume so, but I just want to confirm.)

Regarding range vs. xrange, in Python 3.x, range has replaced xrange.

**Edit with additional information.**

The cause of the crash was due to overflow of internal structures in a 32-bit build. Using a 64-bit version of Python and gmpy or gmpy2 is the proper fix.

The unpack(x,n) function is similar to split() for a string: it divides a number into a series of n-bit values. It is equivalent to, but much faster than:

```
def unpack(x,n):
r = []
m = 2**n
while x:
    x, temp = divmod(x,m)
    r.append(temp)
return r
```

Some documentation is available via `help(gmpy2.unpack)` but better documentaion is on my to-do list.

The reason that unpack() can be used to eliminate the % operation is the same as the adding the digits of base-10 number to check for divisibility for 9. In this case, unpack() creates p-bit numbers and we are dividing by 2**p - 1.

Here is some test code:

```
import gmpy2
import time

def mersenne1(p):
    '''Primality test for Mersenne prime: 2**p -1.
    Uses native Python longs. Does not verify that p is prime.'''

    s = 4
    M = 2**p - 1
    for i in range(p-2):
        s = ((s*s)-2) % M
    return False if s else True

def mersenne2(p):
    '''Primality test for Mersenne prime: 2**p -1.
    Uses gmpy2.mpz. Does not verify that p is prime.'''

    s = gmpy2.mpz(4)
    M = gmpy2.mpz(2)**p - 1
    for i in range(p-2):
        s = ((s*s)-2) % M
    return False if s else True

def mersenne3(p):
    '''Primality test for Mersenne prime: 2**p -1.
    Uses gmpy2.mpz and no mod. Does not verify that p is prime.'''

    s = gmpy2.mpz(4)
    M = gmpy2.mpz(2)**p - 1
    for i in range(p-2):
        s = (s*s)
        s = sum(gmpy2.unpack(s, p))
        s = sum(gmpy2.unpack(s, p))
        if s < 2:
            s = M - 2 + s
        else:
            s = s - 2
    return False if s else True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = 44497

    start = time.time()
    result1 = mersenne1(p)
    print("Elapsed time: {:6.3f}".format(time.time() - start))

    start = time.time()
    result2 = mersenne2(p)
    print("Elapsed time: {:6.3f}".format(time.time() - start))

    start = time.time()
    result3 = mersenne3(p)
    print("Elapsed time: {:6.3f}".format(time.time() - start))

    if result1 == result2 == result3:
        print("All three tests are equal!")
    else:
        print("Oops, something has gone wrong.")
```

And some running times...

```
C:\x64\Python32>python.exe mersenne.py
Elapsed time: 163.683
Elapsed time: 12.782
Elapsed time:  3.630
All three tests are equal!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good call on the 64-bit versions of python and gmpy. That seems to have fixed the problem. Also, I cannot use `pow(s, 2, M)`, I think, because my actual line of code is `s = ((s * s) - 2) % M`. I just left it out for simplicity of the code example.

Comment: ISTR gmp has some kind of a power-modulo function?

Comment: @RyanPeschel It looks like you looking for Mersenne primes. If so, there should be significant performance improvement by replacing the % with some additions. If M=2**n-1, then x % M can be calculated by splitting x into n-bit chunks and adding the chunks. You will need to repeat split/add twice, but it will be faster for large n. The command would be `x=sum(gmpy2.unpack(x, n))`. Experiment with that hint and I'll can post an example later.

Comment: @casevh: Yes I am! I would also greatly appreciate an example on how to further optimize it. I tried looking in the documentation for unpack but I cannot seem to find anything on it.. Also it's giving me an error saying it expects ints when I'm using xmpz's.

Comment: Ahh, apparently if I use mpz's instead of xmpz's for unpack it runs. Still, I'm not exactly sure what summing unpack does as I cannot seem to find any documentation on them.

Comment: @user2284570 There is bug in GMP on 64-bit Windows systems. GMP assumes `long` will be 64-bit but it is only a 32-bit type on Windows. I am testing a change to GMP that should fix the issue. `gmpy2.mpz()` will convert a string to an `mpz` type.

Comment: @casevh : remember cygwin integers size aren’t necessarily the one used by msys/windows. *(cygwin could be implemented as subsystem but they done it over the windows one)*

Comment: @user2284570 My comments are based on msys2 (which is based on cygwin) and the common mingw-w64 compiler suite. I am not aware of any 64-bit Windows C compiler that treats `long` as a 64-bit type and produces standard DLLs and applications.

Comment: @casevh : cygwin as evolved in what could be windows subsystem since the msys fork.

Comment: @user2284570 I've learned something today. The cygwin64 model does use use `long` as a 64-bit type. It probably doesn't help with making an extension module for the commonly used Windows Python interpreters, but it is nice to know. Thanks.